# Android (Java): Programatically adding a custom TableRow View with cells of equal width does not result in cells of equal width

Tags: java, android

In my Android application, I am attempting to programmatically add a custom `TableRow` view (`CustomTableRow`) to a `TableLayout`. `CustomTableRow` has cells of equal length (the first two cells have text, and the third one has a edit and delete button, as shown in the diagram below):
[image]

However, when I programmatically add a `CustomTableRow` to my `TableLayout`, this is the result I get (the cells are all jumbled together instead of occupying equal width):

[image]

This seems strange, considering that I have specified that all cells are to have weight 1 in the XML layout that CustomTableRow inflates. Furthermore, I even programatically set the cells in CustomTableRow to have weight 1 as an extra measure. And yet, the cells are still jumbled together.

Below is my code:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/housemate_data_table"
        layout="@layout/table" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**table.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rent_form"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">
            <TableRow android:background="#d6d7d7" android:padding="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Area"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_table_row.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Area"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:text="E" />

        <Button
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:text="D" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.programaticallyaddtablerowtotablelayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Retrieve of the table layout.
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);

        // Create the housemate's custom TableRow.
        CustomTableRow customTableRow = new CustomTableRow(getApplicationContext(), "Name", "Area");
        customTableRow.findViewById(R.id.col1).setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        customTableRow.findViewById(R.id.col2).setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        customTableRow.findViewById(R.id.col3).setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        customTableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        table.addView(customTableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

**CustomTableRow.java**:

```
package com.example.programaticallyaddtablerowtotablelayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TableRow;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class CustomTableRow extends TableRow {
    public CustomTableRow(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initUI();
    }

    public CustomTableRow(Context context, String name, String areaText) {
        super(context);
        initUI();
    }

    public CustomTableRow(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initUI();
    }

    // Initiate the custom TableRow's UI by inflating the template XML layout.
    private void initUI() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_table_row, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to set layout params width to `MATCH_PARENT` instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` here `customTableRow.findViewById(R.id.col1).setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));`

Answer (score 0):

In `custom_table_row.xml`, changing `TableRow` to the `merge` tag resolved the problem.